# How to load the defualt value in combo box and how can add product to the cart without reloading the page in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

**Problem**
*I want to the following things but am unable to understand that how can I do the following things.*

- Firstly, I want that when the page is loaded the defualt values should be displayed from using the value from the combox. For example pack of 1KG is the defualt value so it's price and other values should be updated when the page is loaded.
- Secondly, I want that when the product is added to the cart the page is not reloaded or refreshed and a popup is shown that the product is added to the cart.

**CODE**

**Script**

```
$(document).on("change", '.tranactionID', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //get closest outer div.. 
        var selector = $(this).closest(".productID")
        //find to get required elements..
        selector.find('.id_price').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("price"));
        selector.find('.price-sale').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("sale_price"));
        selector.find('.id_discount').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("discount"));
        let id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('transID');
        let Url = `{% url 'cart:cart_add' 0 %}`.replace(0, id);
        selector.find("form").attr('action', Url);
    });
```

**HTML**

```
{% regroup transaction by productID as ProductList %}
  {% for productID in ProductList %}
  <div class="col-sm-3 productID" >
    <div class="product">
      <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
        <span class="status id_discount">%</span>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
        <h3><a href="#">{{productID.grouper}}</a></h3>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="pricing">
            <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc id_price">Rs. </span><span class="price-sale">Rs. </span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
          
          <select class="tranactionID" id="ItemID" style="width: 250px;">
            {% for val in productID.list %}
                <option transID={{val.id}} price={{val.Price}} discount={{val.discount_percentage}} sale_price={{val.get_sale}} class="price_value" >{{val.AUID}} - {{val.Description}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
         
         
            <form id='transactionIDValue' class="d-inline" method="post">
              {{cart_product_form}}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="submit" id="Id_submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" value="Add To Cart">
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2">Add to Cart</button> -->
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: For first issue you can use `$(".tranactionID").trigger("change")`  this will call your event handler and update your values and second issue is because you have `type="submit"` so your page reloads because of that .

Comment: you may be interested in htmx https://htmx.org/

Comment: both are not working for me @Swati

Comment: Hi, you need to put this `$(".tranactionID").trigger("change")` on page load and about second issue try using ajax so that page will not get refresh.

Comment: Not working @Swati . Can u please show me how to do it

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pngsr5jx/) for first issue.

Comment: check and updated now it works thanks you for the first issue

Comment: can u explain me a bit about the second so i get ti know needs to be done for it

Comment: I have tried to use ajax but when it goes to the url to add product to the cart is shows an error on the console that the link is forbidden @Swati

Comment: Please ask new question with proper explanation and error which you are facing so that more people can you .